# Database Design Schema

Tags: database-design

[image]

I have a project which we have to make a database for a car dealership. We have to make a Salersperson be able to view the inventory, add sales people, add cars/ car details. A customer must be able to view inventory, add cars they would think about purchasing, and then purchase the car or have a salesperson purchase the car. Salesperson must have their sales saved . I feel like my design looks a bit clunky and could be broken down better in a few more tables, but I am just drawing a blank when thinking about how else to break this up. Any suggestions?

Comment: First suggestion is 1. drop the "id" column - it's going to get in the way of properly modeling the relationships.  As it stands you have no keys (I could insert the same VIN into your `car_desciption` table until I ran out of numbers. You will have composite keys in the correct data model, this is fine.  You may find the steps outlined here useful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271439/mysql-what-are-the-steps-for-creating-a-database-schema-for-a-big-project-with/271440#271440

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by "looks a bit clunky and could be broken down better in a few more tables"; something looking "clunky", however that applies to database design, doesn't seem like a good reason to breaking things up. Unlike fighting the dark force, you probably should use logic, not your feelings.

For a suggestion, may be you could answer (to yourself) to some questions about your model, such as:

Why do you think that "car make/model" is a separate entity and not simply attributes of a "car" entity?

Why `car.car_lot varchar(255)` references `car_lot.lot_id (integer)`?

Why `for_sale_cars`? What entity does that represent?

Is `customer.customer_cars varchar(255)` intended to store a list of cars? That would violate 1NF. And how is that then different from `saved_cars`?

Why do you think you need an extra key in `saved_cars`?

Which of the requirements you have listed *cannot* be addressed by your model? Are there any requirements that are missing?